# Force Uber app to launch when requesting Uber ride within Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, intents, uber

I am a fan of integrating ridesharing (Uber and Lyft) fare results into the travel directions interface of Google Maps, so that I may quickly compare the two companies to each other and to other forms of transportation.  However, I do not like having the entire Uber ride take place within Google maps.  I find the interface inferior to Uber's app (lots of info/options are missing), and I would prefer that the Maps app is available for other searches while riding in the Uber (e.g., looking up the exact location of a restaurant).

**Is there any way to force Maps to launch the Uber app from within these search results?**

The alternative is to

- highlight the address
- select "copy",
- return to the desktop,
- launch the Uber app,
- clear out any Uber messages (e.g., rate your last driver),
- paste the address into the Uber search (which doesn't work if you used something like "home" in Maps),
- confirm that it's the same location on the maps you already found in Google (which might not be the case for overloaded place names),
- confirm your current location,
- and hit the "book"/"request" button.

Do-able, but inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the Uber app to use Uber rather than using Google maps.

Comment: But then I can't compare it with Lyft, public transit, and driving.

Comment: I'd recommend doing g it the way you are doing it then.  Pretty sure there's no way to integrate them like you've explained.